Deploy Next application
i have a vps on ovh, and i have one react website in my vps, it's work very well !
So, now i have a one next site, i have a build and i have push the build on my vps, and he doesn't work i have juste the listing of my files when i want to see my website.
It's my first time i deployed a next web site.
i have install node and pm2 and doesn't work.
Maybe it's my build because i have see i don't have a file "index.html" in my build ?
I have see this tutorial https://dev.to/digitalpollution/your-nextjs-app-your-environment-a-guide-to-deployment-10l
I use Apache
